# Where can I ask questions related to 3ds Max, architecture modelling, and rendering?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

I could not find any site where I can ask 3ds Max modelling related questions.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find a suitable site either.

However, there *was* an [Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5022/3d-graphics) for a 3D Graphics Q&A. It went into Beta but didn't have sufficient statistics to pass off as a successful site.

You are, of course, able to propose this once again, perhaps under a different scope and different name, to get more people interested.

It also seems that Graphic Design has a ["3d" tag](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3d). That may be a suitable place to ask your question.

Comment: Technical questions about 3D software is off topic for the Graphic Design site, per their FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to stick to [CGTalk](http://forums.cgsociety.org/forumdisplay.php?f=6), which currently has 450k posts on Max.